# Release memory when working with PIL

Tags: python, rotation, garbage-collection, python-imaging-library

I'm editing an image with PIL (Python Imaging Library). On each step (convert, rotate, resize ...) there are more images created. (An excerpt from the documentation: "Returns a copy of an image rotated the given number of degrees ...") So I want to release memory.

Do you know whether the following approach saves memory?

```
import PIL.Image

image = PIL.Image.open('Image.jpg')
garbage = image
image = image.convert('RGB')
del garbage
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to make the temporary `garbage` reference.

When the right-hand side of this statement is executed:

```
image = image.convert('RGB')
```

a new Python object is created.

By assigning it back to `image` the old object that `image` used to represent has its reference count reduced to zero, and is sent to the garbage collector.

However, not related to how Python works, I have seen PIL issues where because of genuine bugs memory leaks have formed.  For instance here's a discussion of issues when using Draw text:

[PIL Draw Text Memory Leak](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2002-March/001759.html)

I know that's a really old discussion, but I *still* see that come up sometimes when I use PIL!

Comment: I know of Python's garbage collector. I'm asking because I work with images with 5 MB of size or more. Performing some tasks fills much memory, because many images are created. So I thought releasing the memory as soon as I can. +++ Couldn't it be that Python's garbage collector frees memory too late, so that in the mean time other programs were told that there's too less space for them?

Comment: Are you also using a PIL Image Draw object?

Comment: Yes, I use it to draw text with a TrueType font on an image.

Comment: Comment out the image draw stuff and rerun your application.  I bet you'll see your memory leak disappear.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. My thoughts were not specific to an existing problem I know of. Do you recommend to `del` the font and the draw objects?

Comment: First, I am saying you should not do the draw at all, so you can verify that your 5MB image objects are getting deleted the way you think they are.  Then once you have verified that your memory leak is with the draw text object, then you have to find out what is broken with PIL.  It's probably *not* a Python/deletion error.  I think there is a genuine memory leak issue with PIL.

Comment: I just tested the size of the memory leak with the maximum amount of text draws to expect and I can live with it. Cause if this error is interally to PIL (and exists for at least 10 years), then I don't think I can do anything about it. +++ The `del`s I addressed are another topic. Is the resume that Python's garbage collector is sufficient, or would you say the approach I wrote is reasonable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13394/discussion-between-k-brafford-and-rynd)

Comment: `del` doesn't delete the memory of an object, it removes a variable from a namespace. Are you sure it also triggers GC?