# Memory leak while inserting new element to database using MySQLdb in python

Tags: python, mysql, memory-leaks, mysql-python

I have a folder containing a list of images, from which I am creating a hash of each image and inserting it one by one to an sql database using MySQLdb in python. There are around 1400 images in that folder, whose hashes I need to store in that database. However, with each insertion, it is consuming up some portion of my free RAM, which eventually ends up with 0 free RAM space, and the process gets killed. I don't understand why this is happening because one simple insertion should not result in putting the entire database in the RAM. So the amount of RAM that is consumed while doing an insertion should not depend on the size of the database. Yet, my RAM is getting filled up with time, even though I am doing self.db.close() after every insertion. Why is that happening, and how can I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
def create_hash(userpath, hashfunc=imagehash.phash):
    print "here"
    image_filenames = [os.path.join(userpath, path)
                    for path in os.listdir(userpath) if is_image(path)]
    for img in sorted(image_filenames):
        try:
            hash_img = hashfunc(Image.open(img))
            img_url =  img.split("/")[-1]
            print hash_img
            c = Connection()
            c.insert(img_url, hash_img)
            c.close_connection()
        except Exception,e:
            print str(e)
```

and here is the insert function of the Connection class:

```
class Connection():
def __init__(self):
    self.db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","some_schema")
    self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

def insert(self, image_url, hash_value):
    query = "insert into image_hash (image_url, hash) value (\"%s\",\"%s\")"%(image_url, hash_value)
    print query
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        self.db.commit()
    except Exception,e:
        self.db.rollback()
        print str(e)
def close_connection(self):
    self.db.close()
```

Please note that I am using [this imagehash python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ImageHash) in my code above

Comment: Extremely unlikely to be anything to do with mysql. more likely to do with your hashing. Please post some code

Comment: Can you add your code so we can see what causing this

Comment: Added code. Can you please see what is causing this problem?

Comment: I just checked the ImageHash library and I see that it's an 18MB download wouldn't be at all surprised if the leak is inside that.  comment out the three lines in your create_hash function that deal with the DB and run it again you will see it freaks out.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. It does freak out indeed. I was thinking of putting that for-loop out of that python script, so that, this new python script creates the hash for only one file. And then create a for-loop inside a shell-script instead, which calls the python-script again and again for each of those 1400 files. Does that make sense? Because, by doing that, I am creating a python process, creating and adding hash of image to database, and then killing the process, thus freeing up the RAM again, and this is done 1400 times. Should that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert multiple rows in one query.

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas.

And look is memory still leaking.

```
class Connection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","some_schema")
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

    def insert(self, values):
        query = "insert into image_hash (image_url, hash) values {0}".format(values)
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(query)
            self.db.commit()
        except Exception,e:
            self.db.rollback()
            print str(e)

    def close_connection(self):
        self.db.close()


def create_hash(userpath, hashfunc=imagehash.phash):
    _join = os.path.join
    image_filenames = [_join(userpath, path)
                       for path in os.listdir(userpath) if is_image(path)]
    hash_list = []
    for img in sorted(image_filenames):
        try:
            hash_img = hashfunc(Image.open(img))
            img_url =  img.split("/")[-1]
            hash_list.append("('{0}', '{1}')".format(img_url, hash_img))
        except Exception,e:
            print str(e)


    c = Connection()
    c.insert(', '.join(hash_list))
    c.close_connection()
```

Comment: Did not solve the problem. RAM gets used up as before and process gets killed when free RAM becomes zero, and this is happening even before the control is coming out of the for loop. I guess that adding those 1400 hashes to the hash_list is taking up all the RAM.

Comment: Try to use manual garbage collection http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection
the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337986/memory-leaks-when-image-discarded-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317847/release-memory-when-working-with-pil